# manually featching facebook like, share count not working

Tags: php, facebook

manually getting the count of like, share that seemed to work before is now not working.
`$lines` returned the count of likes and share and other. to get the values i used the following:

```
$postUrl = urlencode(SITEROOT.'gallery_single.php?photo_id='.$rasActImg['id'].'&format=xml');
$lines = file('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='.$postUrl);
```

to display the count of like i used the following:

```
<div class="countNum"><?php echo $lines[6]; ?></div>
```

But now `$lines` is not returning anything.

I also tried the following code but the result is same, nothing is displayed.

```
$url11 = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".$postUrl;
$xml = file_get_contents($url11);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
if(isset($_GET['check'])){
    var_dump($xml);
}
```

**EDIT**

## **This is obsolete by now, facebook probably have new ways to do it.**

Comment: try dumping $lines and show us the result here

Comment: Use the Graph API and not the old Rest api that will be deprecated really soon anyway

Comment: dumping the `$lines` displays `boolen(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

```
$rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($url);

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($rest_url),true);
echo '<p><span>'.$json[0]['share_count'].'</span> Shares</p>';
```

also you can get other count by replacing 'share_count' to 
'like_count'
'comment_count'
'total_count' 
'click_count'

**EDIT**

## **This is obsolete by now, facebook probably have new ways to do it.**

Comment: Try this : https://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}&fields=engagement&access_token={your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}

is working